# Discord.js 12.0.0 msg.content returning blank

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm making a stats checker bot in discord.js v12.0.0 because I don't want to deal with slash commands and intents, just wanted this to be a quick little project that I throw together. But, after coding for a while a command I made didn't work, and I decided to console log msg.content to see if that was the issue. It shows as completely blank when I log msg.content, as well as logging msg itself. NO, I am not running a self bot, I read that doing that can also give this issue.

Images:

[image: Text]

[image: Text]

[image: Text]

Code:

```
import Discord from 'discord.js';
const client = new Discord.Client();
import fetch from 'node-fetch';

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`online`);
});

let lb;

async function fet() {
  await fetch("https://login.deadshot.io/leaderboards").then((res) => {
      return res.json();
  }).then((res) => {
    lb = res;
  })
}

client.on('message', async msg => {
  console.log(msg)
  let channel = msg.channel.id;
  if (msg.author.id == client.user.id) return;
  if (channel != 1015992080897679370) return;
  await fet();
  let r;
  for (var x in lb.all.kills) {
    if (msg.content.toLowerCase() == lb.all.kills[x].name.toLowerCase()) {
      r = lb.all.kills[x].name;
    }
  }
  if (!r) return msg.channel.send('Error: user not found')
})

client.login(token)
```

Answer (score 2):

Discord enforced the Message Content privileged intent, since September 1st.

Here's the announcement from Discord Developers server ([invite](https://discord.gg/discord-developers))
[image: Message Content is N ow A Privileged Intent]

<sup>Source message: [Discord Developers #api-announcements](https://discord.com/channels/613425648685547541/697138785317814292/1014971523439808553)</sup>

You can fix this, but you do need to use intents...

```js
const client = new Discord.Client({
  ws: {
    intents: [Discord.Intents.ALL, 1 << 15]
  }
})
```

You also need to flip the Message Content intent switch in developer portal

It's much better to update to version 13+, v12 is deprecated and is easily broken.